# How to specify VSPackage / VSIX Manifest prereq or install target version range?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vspackage, vsixmanifest

I am trying to limit a VSIX/VSPackage to Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 and up. However, I can't seem to get the correct combination of version numbers.

Looking at the build numbers for VS 2017, I'd expect to enter [15.8.28010.0, 16.0) in the .vsixmanifest in my install targets. However, doing so seems too restrictive as I cannot install the package on VS 2017 15.8.2 (15.8.28010.2016). If I change it to [15.0, 16.0), I can then install the VSIX. However, that is too lenient as I can install the vsix on earlier versions of VS 2017 that I would expect.

I then attempted to leave the install targets to [15.0,16.0) and tried tightening the prereqs for the Visual Studio Core Editor. If I choose edit, it prepopulates the range with [15.8.27729.1,16.0). According to Microsoft's documentation, version 15.8.27729.1 is Visual Studio 15.8.0 Preview 2. Why that version? What is it using to determine what version to auto populate? I'd expect it to maybe be the current version of VS 2017 I am using, but that would mean it should have autopopulated with 15.8.28010.2016.

Bottom line, what version number should I be using to restrict to Visual Studio 2017 15.8 and above?

Comment: 15.8.28010.0 according to the docs

Comment: That's what I tried to use...:
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -    Version : [15.8.28010.0,16.0)
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -    Version : [15.8.28010.0,16.0)
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM -    Version : [15.8.28010.0,16.0):24 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
11/6/2018 2:53:24 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.